# Can MKV hold VP8 Opus combination, and how

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codec, mkv, vp8

I want to create a MKV file with video codec `VP8` and audio codec `opus`

I tried the following command in ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -y -i ./INPUT.flv -threads 8  -aspect 16:9 -vcodec libvpx  -vb 2M -acodec libopus   -ac 2 OUTPUT.mkv
```

I have installed libopus0 in my Ubuntu, but I am getting this error:

```
Duration: 00:07:53.30, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 541 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 640x360, 410 kb/s, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 131 kb/s
Unknown encoder 'libopus0'
```

What is the problem, and how can I correct this issue?

Comment: Maybe webm is more suitable for vp8+opus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ffmpeg` allows VP9/VP8 & Opus in Matroska (MKV/MKA). Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libvpx-vp9 -c:a libopus output.mkv
```

- Users of old versions will have to add `-strict experimental` for Opus.
- Users of ancient versions will not be able to mux Opus into Matroska.

Comment: Is there any official specification for opus support in mkv?

Answer (score 2):

```
ffmpeg -codecs | grep opus
```

Yields

```
DEA.L. opus  Opus (Opus Interactive Audio Codec) (decoders: libopus )
             (encoders: libopus )
```

So perhaps you can run like this

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -c:v libvpx -c:a opus a.mkv
```

Comment: Seem I found the issue but am unable to solve it. Am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I cant find libopus or opus-tools in my repository. Universe and multiverse are active. I did not get an output for `ffmpeg -codecs | grep opus`

Comment: @BMC Opus only comes in [12.10 with `libopus-dev`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+package/libopus-dev). You could simply compile it from source.